# Comparing data of specific node with parallel data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If my database looks like this:

```
database
   |_______id1
   |        |_______dataKey1: dataValue1
   |        |_______dataKey2: dataValue2
   |
   |_______id2
   |        |_______dataKey1: dataValue3
   |        |_______dataKey2: dataValue4
   |
   |_______id3
            |_______dataKey1: dataValue5
            |_______dataKey2: dataValue6
```

Assuming I am currently working with the user with `id1`, and I want to compare each `dataValue1` and `dataValue2` with the rest of the datas, ie `dataValue3`, `dataValue4`,`dataValue5` and `dataValue6` (assume they are integers for example).

Right now I can simply get `dataValue1` and `dataValue2` using simple callback with a listener and `onDataChange`. I save these values in an ArrayList. So far everything is OK. But how to compare the data saved in the ArrayList with the rest of the data? I thought about looping through the ArrayList, and for each data in the ArrayList create another async callback to fetch the rest of the data. But it will make some nested async callbacks, and also call to the rest of the data many times (the amount of the values that the current user has) and I guess it's not the correct way to do that? It's something that should be easy to do, but with all that async callbacks I get stuck

Comment: what do you mean by compare?  If one or both values for `dataKey1` and `dataKey2` for the user with `id1` equals those values for the other users?

Comment: "I guess it's not the correct way to do that?" I prefer to not guess about such things. If it works, and meets your requirement, then that sounds good to me. If it doesn't work, and you think it should, include the [minimal code with which we can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.